# How did Facebook calculate the 3.5 degrees of separation of everyone on their platform? (Bitwise Operators question)

Tags: statistics, logic

A few years ago the Facebook team calculated that everyone was an average 3.5 degrees of separation away from every other user on the FB platform.

https://research.fb.com/three-and-a-half-degrees-of-separation/

They explain the maths later in the article.

First they use a statistical approximation of the number of friends you have based on the max number of zeros (n) in a binary hash of your friends ID's.

`Friends ~= c * 2^n where c is a constant`

This much I understand.

Then they go on to say...

> By using a bitwise OR operation on the hash, this process can be repeated recursively to estimate the number of unique friends-of-friends, and then friends-of-friends-of-friends.

What does this part mean?